# Sentinel 5P dataset NO2 monthly means

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

I was trying to find monthly means of S5P Nitrogen Dioxide L3 Product using GEE but found out that the values calculated was less than previously calculated by myself using S5P NO2 L2 datasets. The values obtained were also way less than already quoted in literature also. I noted that there shold be 3 swaths for particular 2 dates as mention in image. But there were 14 images in the image collection, which can reduce the mean monthly NO2 values.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

I was trying to take max NO2 values for single day and then get monthly mean from these daily max values using this code

```
 var NO2_Col = dayOffsets.map(function(dayOffset) {
    var start = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days')
    var end = start.advance(1, 'days')
    var dayOfYear = start.getRelative('day', 'year')
    var filt_images = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2")
    .filterBounds(Clipfile)
    .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
    .filter(ee.Filter.date(start.format("YYYY-MM-dd"), end.format("YYYY-MM-dd")))
    // .map(rescale)
    //.map(clipcol)
    var filt1 = filt_images.first()
    return ee.Image(filt_images
    .map(clipcol)
    .max()
    .copyProperties(filt1, filt1.propertyNames())
    // .max().copyProperties(filt1,['system:time_start','system:time_end'])
    .set('end_date', end.format("YYYY-MM-dd")) 
    .set('start_date', start.format("YYYY-MM-dd"))
    .set('day_of_year', dayOfYear))
  }
)

print("before collection",NO2_Col)

NO2_Col =  ee.ImageCollection(NO2_Col)


// Map filtering and reducing across year-month combinations and convert to ImageCollection
var yrMo = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
          return ee.Image(NO2_Col
          .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
          .mean()
          .set('year',y)
          .set('month',m))
        });
    }).flatten());
    
print("yrMo",yrMo);
yrMo = yrMo.toBands().clip(Clipfile)
print("yrMo",yrMo);

print(NO2_Col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2023, 2023, 'year')))
         
          
          
var MeansMonthlyFeatures = yrMo.reduceRegions({
  collection: Clipfile,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1113.2,
}).map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('imageId', yrMo.id()).setGeometry(null);
    });
```

But I am getting this error

[image]

Can anyone help to solve this issue??